# Python Password Cracker

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

My code is

```
from random import *
guess = ""
password = input("Password: ")
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
while (guess != password):
    for letter in password:
        guessletter = letters[randint(0, 25)]
        guess = str(guessletter) + str(guess)
    print(guess)
print("Password guessed!")
input("")
```

My goal is to get it to randomly generate letters and stick them together to make the length of the password, and do this until it finds the password. Every time I run it, it just makes the command prompt look like something from the Matrix. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I'm doing this to see how hard it would be to crack a password. I have no intent of hacking into other people's accounts.

Comment: You are printing all your guesses, because `print(guess)` is in the `while` loop. Don't print all guesses if you didn't want to do that.

Comment: But all the guesses aren't the length of the password, and it can never guess the password, even if it's just 3 letters.

Comment: I think you want to reset your guess to empty string at the beginning of each while loop

Comment: Where are you resetting `guess` to the empty string?

Comment: That worked! :D Thanks!

Comment: [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips for debugging code. Using these techniques you could probably find the problem on your own. Debugging is a critical skill to learn for just such situations that come up all the time when you are writing code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice dude its been 4 years

Comment: lol, my bad. This showed up in the homepage so I took a look, but didn't look at the date. Looks like someone recently posted an answer

Comment: @Code-Apprentice xD thanks for your response tho. I have to say I've gotten a lot better at debugging over the past 4 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already said, you are not properly resetting your guess.

Also, that's not how you crack passwords, since you are repeating the same guesses over and over. You need to somehow go over all the possibilities, without repeating yourself.

Say your password is 4 letters long, you can start with aaaa, then aaab, until zzzz. You may do it in another order, a random one, but you should test each case only once.

Comment: And if you don't know anything about the password, going alphabetically is as effective as going random I think!

Comment: In fact neither is the best. Cracking tools use methods based on statistics to define the order it is most likely to find the password first.

Comment: How would one do that? (the systematic way)

Answer (score 2):

You never reset "guess" so it just keeps getting bigger and bigger.

```
from random import *
guess = ""
password = input("Password: ")
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
while (guess != password):
    guess = ""
    for letter in password:
        guessletter = letters[randint(0, 25)]
        guess = str(guessletter) + str(guess)
    print(guess)
print("Password guessed!")
input("")
```

Comment: What about when the size of the password is not known?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the code a bit to include `itertools.permutations(guess)` to get all the possible combination of that random guess and test against it. This will save some time.

```py
from random import *
import itertools


guess = ""
password = input("Password: ")
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]


while (guess != password):
    guess = ""
    perm = ""
    for letter in password:
        guessletter = letters[randint(0, 25)]
        guess = str(guessletter) + str(guess)

        perm = itertools.permutations(guess)
        
    for p in perm:                    
        guess = "".join(p)
        print(" ",guess,end="\r")
            
            
print(f"Password guessed! ==> {guess}")
input("")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
guess = ""
password = input("Password: ")
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
while (guess != password):
    guess = ""
    for letter in password:
        guess letter = letters[rand ant(0, 25)]
        guess = sir(guess letter) + sir(guess)
    print(guess)
print("Password guessed!")
input("")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from random import *

guess = ""

password = input (" password: ")

letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",   "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",]

while (guess != password):
    for letter in password:
      guessletter = letters[randint(0.25)]
      guess = str(guessletter) str(guess)
    print(guess)

print( "password guessed!")
```